# Visual Studio 2022 17.3.2 AngularJS Intellisense and Outlining

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Yesterday, I updated Visual Studio 2022 to version 17.3.2, everything was working fine before this update...

With this update, Intellisense and Outlining is not working for AngularJS, for example...

1. I can't see list of methods in top page:

[image]

2. Now doesn't work Ctrl+M + Ctrl+A for collapse all code
3. I cant expand or collapse any region with +/- icon in the left panel

... etc

With Visual Studio Code works everything ok:

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Asking the obvious but - have you restarted your computer since the updating?

Comment: Yes, I have restarted pc

Comment: Perhaps try the preview version of Visual Studio.  A future update may have fixed this.  The bug tracker for Visual Studio is too difficult to try and look through to see if this is in fact a bug or not.